# RGB Me.BackColor Simple Apps

Tags: rgb, vb.net-2010

My name is Danny. I'm just starting to learn about coding for fun and using VB 2010. I want to write an app which when we input an RGB value between 0 to 255 in each box (R,G,B) and hit the "display color". The background of my app will change to that RGB color. I already got to the basic, but I couldn't finish the rest. Here is what I want:
1. When we leave one of the boxes blank, the message box will pop up: "Please...!"
2. When we enter value <0 or >255 in each box, the message box will show.

Here is what I got so far:

```
Public Class RGB
Dim r1 As Integer
Dim g1 As Integer
Dim b1 As Integer

'Display Color Button'
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles dis.Click
    r1 = r.Text
    g1 = g.Text
    b1 = b.Text
    Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r1, g1, b1)

    Convert.ToInt32(r.Text)
    Convert.ToInt32(g.Text)
    Convert.ToInt32(b.Text)
    If r.Text Or g.Text Or b.Text = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Input The Value!")
    Else : Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r1, g1, b1)
    End If

    If r.Text Or g.Text Or b.Text < 0 or > 255Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Value Between 0 and 255")
    Else : Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r1, g1, b1)
    End If
End Sub

'Exit App Confirmation'
Private Sub Form_FormClosing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosing
    Dim response As MsgBoxResult
    response = MsgBox("Do you want to close?", MsgBoxStyle.Question + MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, "Confirm")
    If response = MsgBoxResult.Yes Then
        Me.Dispose()
    ElseIf response = MsgBoxResult.No Then
        e.Cancel = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example for java applet as you haven't specified which languaje:

```
    if(values are correct){
            try{
                paint whatever you need
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Hello you misstiped the values");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your evaluations are slightly off. Try using this:

```
'replace your evals with this:
If IsValid(r.text) And IsValid(r.text) And IsValid(r.text) Then
        Me.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(CInt(r.text), CInt(g.text), CInt(b.text))
Else
      'your generic errror message
End If

Private Function IsValid(ByVal val As String) As Boolean
    Dim bRet As Boolean = False
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(val) Then
        If IsNumeric(val) Then
            If CInt(val) >= 0 And CInt(val) <= 255 Then
                bRet = True

            End If
        End If
    End If

    Return bRet
End Function
```

Comment: But if `r.text` is a `string`, can you really compare it with a less-than operator? I'm really confused about him writing `Convert.ToInt32(r.Text)` but *NOT* saving the return value in any variable.

Comment: .net is forgiving. it will implicitly convert the value to compare it. If you want it more explicit you could wrap r.text like this : cint(r.text) but you may want to check that it's a number prior using isnum(r.text). If you like I can edit the answer to streamline the entire validation routine